# ie browser not entering into dispose function and not showing the pdf format

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button as 'save as pdf'. on clicking on that button, it will create a pdf format of that page. It is working fine in chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

I am giving the code below, where IE not at all entering into the dispose function and not showing the alert also... Please help me to fix this issue.

```
function (dispose) {      
     alert("function called");
      pdf.save('Software.pdf');     
}
```

Comment: what is `pdf`? which libraries are you using? which version of ie? what is the error message saying? do you even lift bruh?

Comment: this is the js file, i have included    <script src="/ITServiceCatalog/Documents/ITPortal.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and this is html code for that button   <button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML()" type="button" id="buttonPDF" disabled="">Save as PDF</button>   and this is the code for demofromhtml()...........

Comment: i am not able to give that much of code... so,pls tell me is there any option to upload files.. or give long number of text